# How to render amount selected items with react-select v2

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) version 2 and I'm having trouble to change the custom behavior for multi selects. I would like to show the amount of items selected instead of the list of selected items. 
I mean instead of this: 
[image]

I want this: 
[image: ![enter image description here]

Any help will be really appreciated!

thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom `components` to do something like this:

**UPDATE with @lisdey89 open menu behaviour**

```
const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { getValue, hasValue } = props;
  const nbValues = getValue().length;
  if (!hasValue) {
    return (
      <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
        {children}
      </components.ValueContainer>
    );
  }
  return (
    <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
      {`${nbValues} items selected`}
    </components.ValueContainer>
  );
};
const options = [
  { label: "label 1", value: 1 },
  { label: "label 2", value: 2 },
  { label: "label 3", value: 3 },
  { label: "label 4", value: 4 }
];
function App() {
  const components = { ValueContainer };
  return <Select isMulti components={components} options={options} />;
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ox7415oll9).

Comment: Nice, but in your example drop down list doesn't show after click on label, only when you clicked a arrow. Did you think about that?

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try, however as pointed by @only_one the default onClick behavior is no longer working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After I continue searching based on @Laura's answer I end up with this solution to show the amount of items selected and also maintain the ValueContainer default behavior, maybe someone else could find it useful:

```
const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { getValue, hasValue } = props;
  const nbValues = getValue().length;
  if (!hasValue) {
    return (
      <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
        {children}
      </components.ValueContainer>
    );
  }
  return (
    <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
      {
        `${nbValues} items selected`
      }
    </components.ValueContainer>
  );
};
```

Here an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjvkzk1nn)

Comment: When `isMulti` is set to true, this fails to close on clickaway